# If I assign a procedure to an object property, can it reference other properties of the object?

Tags: object, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Best shown with a simple example, question is the ShowMessage at the bottom:

```
type
  TFrmSelfRef = class(TForm)
    BtnTest: TButton;
    procedure BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
    procedure ExternalCaller;
  end;

type
   TProcType = procedure of Object;

type
   TSomeObj = class
   private
      FIdentifier: Integer;
      FCaller    : TProcType;
   public
      property Caller     : TProcType read FCaller write FCaller;
      property Identifier : integer read FIdentifier write FIdentifier;
   end;

[snip]

procedure TFrmSelfRef.BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   lSomeObj: TSomeObj;
begin
   lSomeObj := TSomeObj.Create;
   lSomeObj.Identifier := 200;
   lSomeObj.Caller := ExternalCaller;
   lSomeObj.Caller;
   lSomeObj.Free;
end;

procedure TFrmSelfRef.ExternalCaller;
begin
   ShowMessage('Can I access lSomeObj.Identifier (value:200) here?');
end;
```

Reason: I already have a TSomeObj instance containing all the information Caller would require, but the ExternalCaller references other objects/units that I do not want to link (the unit containing) TSomeObj to.

Comment: Would `Sender` argument be an option? `TProcType = procedure(Sender: TSomeObj) of object`.

Answer (score 4):

[Peter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60262902/if-i-assign-a-procedure-to-an-object-property-can-it-reference-other-properties/60263107#comment106595800_60262902) shows a possibility. It needs some forwarding trickery:

```
type
  TSomeObj = class; 

  TFrmSelfRef = class(TForm)
    BtnTest: TButton;
    procedure BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
    procedure ExternalCaller(ASomeObj: TSomeObj);
  end;

  TProcType = procedure(Sender: TSomeObj) of Object;

  TSomeObj = class
  private
    FIdentifier: Integer;
    FCaller    : TProcType;
  public
    property Caller     : TProcType read FCaller write FCaller;
    property Identifier : integer read FIdentifier write FIdentifier;
  end;

[snip]

procedure TFrmSelfRef.BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  lSomeObj: TSomeObj;
begin
  lSomeObj := TSomeObj.Create;
  lSomeObj.Identifier := 200;
  lSomeObj.Caller := ExternalCaller;
  lSomeObj.Caller(lSomeObj);
end;

procedure TFrmSelfRef.ExternalCaller(ASomeObj: TSomeObj);
begin
  ShowMessage('I can access TSomeObj here! Identifier property value: ' + IntToStr(ASomeObj.Identifier));
end;
```

Comment: Yes, this is the most natural solution. (I suggested it in my initial comment, but thought you were against such an explicit connection between the objects.)

Comment: Note that this is basically a typed TNotifyEvent. IOW, as mentionned by Andreas, a very idiomatic approach.

Comment: @Ken What do you mean with an *idiomatic* approach? And oh yes!, let me investigate TNotifyEvents too... ;-)

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94563/what-is-idiomatic

Comment: @Jan: `TNotifyEvent` is probably the most common event handler type in the VCL. It's the type of almost all `OnClick`, `OnDblClick`, `OnChange`, `OnEnter`, `OnExit`, ... event handlers. You certainly have seen its signature `procedure(Sender: TObject) of object` many times. This is like your `TProcType`, but with a generic `TObject` instead of a more specialised `TSomeObj`. So if you use a `TNotifyEvent`, you'll need to cast `Sender` to `TSomeObj` (and, if you aren't 100% sure it is of that type, you'll need to handle that as well). Either `TSomeObj(Sender)` if you are 100% sure, or ...

Comment: (cont.) ... or `Sender as TSomeObj` if it "really should" be of that type every time and exceptions are not to be expected, or `if Sender is TSomeObj then {do something with TSomeObj(Sender)} else HandleThisScenario` otherwise.

Comment: This answer makes it look like if the question asked if it's possible to pass a parameter to a procedure or not.... Andreas' deleted answer is the correct one IMHO...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: I'll undelete it.

Comment: @Sertac, I Agree. I really don't see how this answers the *question*.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible.

Although `ExternalCaller` *is* a method -- and `TProcType` is a method type ("of object") -- the hidden `Self` parameter for `ExternalCaller()` refers to the `TFrmSelfRef` object that creates `lSomeObj`; it does not refer to `lSomeObj`.

---

Also, you probably already know this, but *never* write

```
lSomeObj := TSomeObj.Create;
lSomeObj.Identifier := 200;
lSomeObj.Caller := ExternalCaller;
lSomeObj.Caller;
lSomeObj.Free;
```

Instead, write

```
lSomeObj := TSomeObj.Create;
try
  lSomeObj.Identifier := 200;
  lSomeObj.Caller := ExternalCaller;
  lSomeObj.Caller;
finally
  lSomeObj.Free;
end;
```

If an exception occurs (or you leave by using `Exit` or `Break` or `Continue`) -- as is normal in Delphi -- you mustn't leak memory and other resources! *Always* use `try..finally` to protect resources.

Comment: @JanDoggen: But of course there are various workarounds and hacks you can use. Maybe someone else can come up with something clever. (But is it worth it? Hacks make the code less readable.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is *possible* with some ugly `TMethod` hackery, eg:

```pascal
type
  TFrmSelfRef = class(TForm)
    BtnTest: TButton;
    procedure BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
    procedure ExternalCaller;
  end;

type
  TProcType = procedure of object;

type
  TSomeObj = class
  private
    FIdentifier: Integer;
    FCaller : TProcType;
  public
    property Caller : TProcType read FCaller write FCaller;
    property Identifier : Integer read FIdentifier write FIdentifier;
  end;

...

procedure TFrmSelfRef.BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  lSomeObj: TSomeObj;
  P: TProcType;
begin
  lSomeObj := TSomeObj.Create;
  try
    lSomeObj.Identifier := 200;

    //lSomeObj.Caller := ExternalCaller;
    P := ExternalCaller;
    TMethod(P).Data := lSomeObj;
    lSomeObj.Caller := P;

    lSomeObj.Caller;
  finally
    lSomeObj.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TFrmSelfRef.ExternalCaller;
begin
  ShowMessage('The Identifier is ' + IntToStr(TSomeObj(Self).Identifier));
end;
```

But this very dangerous if misused. I do not recommend this approach!  I am only presenting it for completeness sake.

Use Peter's solution instead.

Another solution is to move `ExternalCaller()` to `TSomeObj`, eg:

```pascal
type
  TFrmSelfRef = class(TForm)
    BtnTest: TButton;
    procedure BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

type
  TProcType = procedure of object;

type
  TSomeObj = class
  private
    FIdentifier: Integer;
    FCaller : TProcType;
  public
    procedure ExternalCaller;
    property Caller : TProcType read FCaller write FCaller;
    property Identifier : Integer read FIdentifier write FIdentifier;
  end;

...

procedure TFrmSelfRef.BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  lSomeObj: TSomeObj;
  P: TProcType;
begin
  lSomeObj := TSomeObj.Create;
  try
    lSomeObj.Identifier := 200;
    lSomeObj.Caller := lSomeObj.ExternalCaller;
    lSomeObj.Caller;
  finally
    lSomeObj.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TSomeObj.ExternalCaller;
begin
  ShowMessage('The Identifier is ' + IntToStr(Identifier));
end;
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree with the trickery - I won't do that. But moving ExternalCaller() into TSomeObj was what I was trying to prevent....

Comment: Indeed, this was the first hack that sprung to my mind, too. In some cases, it might actually be a good solution (I have used it once in my own code), but most often, it's probably not.